# If statement inside a foreach loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
@foreach ($image as $image)

        <div class="col-md-4">

        @if ($image->current_step == 'step'.$loop->iteration AND $image->isCompleted == '1')
            <div class="panel panel-success">

        @elseif ($image->current_step == 'step'.$loop->first OR $image->current_step == 'step'.$loop->index AND $image->isCompleted == '1')
            <div class="panel panel-default">

        @elseif ($image->current_step == 'step'.$loop->iteration AND $image->isCompleted == '0')
            <div class="panel panel-danger">


        @endif
@endforeach
```

I've created a loop to generate a number of panels, however I want the panels to be styled differently based off the correct if statements.

It seems to be getting stuck on the second if statement whenever it hits that part to ask if the previous steps condition has been met.

If anyone can point me in the general direction or another way I should be going.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use `AND` and `OR` rather than `&&` and `||` ?

Comment: @Luke - yes you can

Comment: @Gravy - can you find me some relevant documentation ? I know you can use standard logical operators but can't find any mention of english language alternatives.

Comment: @Luke why would you use AND and OR rather than using && and ||

Comment: @Gayan I would not. but the OP has which I suspected may be the cause of his/her issues.

Comment: @Luke http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @Erasersharp - can you include your generated HTML so that we can see what is going on?

Comment: @Erasersharp - I think your issue in second step might be an issue because you haven't got brackets to force precedence. `$image->current_step == 'step'.$loop->first OR $image->current_step == 'step'.$loop->index AND $image->isCompleted == '1'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your second else if:

```
    $a = false;
    $b = true;
    $c = false;

    if ($a or $b and $c) {
        dd('a or b and c');
    }

    dd(false);
```

// Above snippet will output false. Is this intended?

You could write a truth table to help you out

```
A  B  C  |  A  |  B  &  C
-------------------------

0  0  0  |  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  1  |  0  0  0  0  1  
0  1  0  |  0  0  1  0  0  
0  1  1  |  0  1  1  1  1  
1  0  0  |  1  1  0  0  0  
1  0  1  |  1  1  0  0  1  
1  1  0  |  1  1  1  0  0  
1  1  1  |  1  1  1  1  1
```